# nsswitch.conf - cannot modify (read-only)

Tags: ubuntu, hosts

I am attempting to modify nsswitch.conf from:

> hosts: files dns

to

> hosts: dns files

But, it is read-only. I have tried using:

> sudo vi /etc/nsswitch.conf

And even with

> :w!

It is unable to modify the file. How can I go about doing this? Currently my system is unable to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change permissions on the file first:

```
sudo chmod u+w /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

That will give write permission to the owner (should be root). Then try editing it as you tried before:

```
sudo vi /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

Comment: Tried this, and it gives me the same result, perhaps the chmod is not working? When I attempt it says: Changing permissions of '/...': Read-only file system. Then, when I attempt to save with vim it says: "nsswitch.conf" E212: Can't open file for writing.

Comment: Read-only file system? Are you running from an Ubuntu Live CD?

Comment: I am not, I am actually on a VPS, I am trying a reinstall, I'll check back a little later.

Comment: Well, that's quite odd. I've reinstalled and it is no longer a read-only system. Not sure what happened, but everything seems great. Thank you.

Comment: Btw: I will vote you up when I get the reputation. haha.